# Nested ng-click argument undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am using a Dynamic list created using ng repeat. Each item has a ng-click on it . But few items are conditioned  which makes a form appear and the form submit again have a ng click on it.
Here is my HTML.

```
<div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">Services
    <span class="caret"></span></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu list-group">
      <li>
          <div class="input-group"> 
         <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model='dfilter.Name' class="form-control">
      </div>   
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class= "service_list_li" ng-repeat="d in services | filter:dfilter"  ng-click="hitDrupal(d.Name,d.endpoint,d.api)">{{ d.Name }}</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <div>
   <form name="dynamic_fields">
     <input type="text" ng-model="drupDynam.one"  ng-if="drupal_dynamic1">
     <input type="text" ng-model="drupDynam.two"  ng-if="drupal_dynamic2" >
     <input type="submit" ng-disabled="dynamic_fields.$pending" ng-click="goDynamic(drupDynam)"  value="Go!" ng-show="drupal_dynamic1">
   </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
 $scope.hitDrupal = function(Name,endpoint,api)
{
  $scope.drupal_dynamic1 = false;
  $scope.drupal_dynamic2 = false;
  if (endpoint=='login') {
     //Do something
  }
  else if (Name == 'New') {
       $scope.drupal_dynamic1 = true;
       $scope.goDynamic = function(drupDynam)
       {
          dynamic_api = api + '/' + drupDynam.one;
          console.log(dynamic_api);
          //Do Something
       }
  }
else
{
 //Do Something 
}
}
```

So the Issue is i am getting the all arguments for the hitDrupal function. i.e Name,endpoint and api. But getting an undefined for second ngclick argument i.e drupDynam.

I have tried passing individual variables also instead of the comlete object. 
I have used ng-submit on the form instead of ng-click.
But no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `drupDynam` in the template, it should be on scope. So you don't need to pass it as an argument. I would say, that the following should work if `drupDynam.one` and `drupDynam.two` work in the template properly:

```
$scope.goDynamic = function() {
   dynamic_api = api + '/' + $scope.drupDynam.one;
   console.log(dynamic_api);
}
```

If no, then something's not ok with `drupDynam` initialization. You may try to output it right in the template:

```
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="dynamic_fields.$pending" ng-click="goDynamic(drupDynam)"  value="Go!" ng-show="drupal_dynamic1">
drupDynam: {{drupDynam}} drupDynam.one: {{drupDynam.one}}
```

By the two-way binding the view must be changed immediately after the value of `drupDynam` is changed on scope, so you'll be able to see it before the click. And if it's not good, you need to investigate the `drupDynam` assignments in code. Where do you set its value?

Comment: The first method worked. But my concern is why doesn't the argument was empty. Is it something related to the watch and apply cycle. or some implementation issue. thanks Anyway

Comment: @ronit That needs to be investigated seperatelly. For me it's not obvious from the code you put in question. I can make a research for you, if you create a Plunker/fiddle/whatever demo.

Comment: No Probs...anyways...Thanxx